# Should I replace wiring harness? If yes, how to do it?

Tags: engine, electrical, battery, wiring

My Hyundai Tucson 2013's fog light is  not working. Also a bulb in cabin which is supposed to stay steady is blinking. I suspect this could be because of the voltage drops and electrical faults.

I inspected the harness and it loos quite old. Where can I get a good quality wiring harness? How should I determine if it is good? Which video or guide should I follow to replace it?

PS: I am an amateur mechanic. Have changed many components myself.

Comment: Don't replace a wiring harness unless you have a very good reason, just because it looks old is not a good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution is to fix these two problems and correct a few other common faults. Use a voltmeter or a test light to confirm if the switch is receiving and outputing 12 volt power. Then go to the bulb and see if it is receiving power. Even with power, the bulb would not work if the ground side is poor, or the bulb is open circuit.

Also, look for grounding points that are corroded. Use sandpaper to clean each lug, then reassemble. Always disconnect the negative terminal when doing work. Then all positive wires are safe, they have no return path.

Changing a wiring harness is a huge undertaking, even for an experienced mechanic. Doing good troubleshooting and spot repairs will get you there.